Is it possible to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{x} \frac{a^{i}}{(x-i)!}$?
I'm trying to calculate next sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x} \frac{e^{-\alpha i}}{(x-i)!}  \lambda^{x-i} \;\sim\; \sum_{i=1}^{x} \frac{a^{i}}{(x-i)!}$$
I've noticed this sum is several first elements of Taylor series for $e^{a}$. Can this fact help me?
I got this sum calculating probability density of random variable $\xi + \eta$, where $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent random variables.
Is there any way to calculate this sum?

This sum equals
$$
e^{-\alpha x}
\sum_{k=0}^{k-1} \frac{(e^\alpha \lambda)^k}{k!}.
$$
The term in the summation is just a truncated Taylor series and it cannot be simplified further, unfortunately.

$$e^{-y}\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\frac{y^k}{k!}=\int_y^{\infty}e^{-t}\frac{t^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}dt$$ is checked by taking derivative of both sides by $y$. It provides an integral representation of what you need. May be you will find it useful.
